# Should objects be singular since arrays are plural?

Tags: javascript, code-quality, naming, array, semantics

Might be a silly question, but what is more logical:

`object.actions.bark()` or `object.action.bark()`?

Simply about plurality. I know arrays are usually pluralized. But if I were to be consistent; ideally, objects should be singular in nature, right?

I guess you could say my example was more of an `associative array` rather than an `object`. But doesn't an `action` object possess properties like `bark()`, much like how `object` object possesses the `action` property.

PS:

This is not opinion-based! It's a very objective inquiry on quality, documentation, and optimization. Imagine the chaos if this was subjective!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57244/discussion-on-question-by-vic-should-objects-be-singular-since-arrays-are-plural).

Answer (score 3):

OK, so javascript has an oddity (amongst many) in that objects are in a way also collections.

But this shouldnt affect your naming. In OOP you should generally try to name objects as they would be called in real life and the Methods of those objects are things the object can do.

so:

```
dog.Bark()

cat.Meiow()
```

etc

now you might have a complex object with sub objects or collections of objects. But again the naming should map to the real thing.

```
company.employees[5].fire()
```

It would be odd to create an object and use it like a collection

```
company.employees.bobsmith.fire()
```

even though such a thing is (in JS) equivalent to a collection of key value pairs

```
company.employees['bobsmith'].fire()
```

If you are going to write OO code in javascript its best to pretend that its strongly typed even though its not.

Comment: So you're saying that `company.employees` is a collection???

Comment: everything is a collection in JS, your only choice is the type of collection